# Realm observer not removed

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using a small helper class like this

```
class RealmWatcher<T>(private val query: RealmResults<T>,
                      private val handler: (RealmResults<T>) -> Unit,
                      private val logger: Logger? = null) {

    private val handlerWrapper: (RealmResults<T>) -> Unit = { result ->
        logger?.trace("⟳  '$result")
        handler.invoke(query)
    }

    fun start() {
        stop()
        handler.invoke(query)
        query.addChangeListener(handlerWrapper) 
    }

    fun stop() {
        query.removeChangeListener(handlerWrapper)
    }
}
```

to `start` and `stop` the listeners in my fragments in `onResume` and `onPause``

Now I am seeing that those observers are note removed correctly. I have gone deep into Realm and see those lines in `OsResults`

```
public <T> void removeListener(T observer, RealmChangeListener<T> listener) {
    removeListener(observer, new RealmChangeListenerWrapper<T>(listener));
}
```

Which leads me to my assumption that there is a bug inside realm. Because a new `RealmChangeListenerWrapper` wrapper is created, and the

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof RealmChangeListenerWrapper &&
                listener == ((RealmChangeListenerWrapper) obj).listener;
    }
```

fails because its a different listener, and thus won't be removed.

**Am I doing something wrong or is this a realm bug?**

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof RealmChangeListenerWrapper &&
            listener == ((RealmChangeListenerWrapper) obj).listener;
}
```

Both `addListener` and `removeListener` create a `RealmChangeListenerWrapper`, so that's definitely true.

It verifies that `listener` is the same instance as the other `listener`, so that should work too if you're removing the same listener you registered previously.

So assuming you call

```
realmWatcher.start()
// change listener should be added
realmWatcher.stop()
// change listener should be removed
```

Then the observer should be removed properly from the RealmResults, because `handlerWrapper` is the same instance both times.

If that doesn't happen, I'd appreciate a sample github project that reproduces this.